# mongo aggregation multiple collection under object

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, both of them have child object, that i want to select left join

here first collection

```
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "62e8b6a6bbc80e944054c5dd"
 },
"id": 143,
"name": "Bengkulu",
"lat": -3.838541,
"lng": 102.388907,
"current_weather": {
"id": 149715,
"dt": "2022-08-02T04:00:00",
"weather": "Cloudy"}
}
```

and this is my second collection

```
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "62e8b84869bbdc2deddeb7a6"
},
"id": 142,
"name": "Aceh",
"lat": 5.510165,
"lng": 95.404572,
"forecast_weather": {
"dt": "2022-08-02T04:00:00",
"rain_probability": 12,
"temperature": 28.9,
"weather": "Cloudy"
}
}
```

I try to use aggregation lookup and match then try to get the data, but object forecast_weather not show any data

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$lookup: {
  from: "data_forecast",
  localField: "id",
  foreignField: "id",
  as: "forecast"}},
{
$unwind: "$forecast"
},{
$match: {
  $and: [
    {"current_weather.dt": {"$gte":"2022-08-03 22:00:00"}}]}
},
{
$project: {
  id: 1,name:1,lat:1,forecast_weather:1,
  name: "$forecast.name"}}])
```

How to show both current_weather and forecast_weather?

Comment: can you please add your expected result in our question.

Comment: Looks like your date format are different. One uses `T` and the other one `_`.

Comment: @turivishal {"id":..., "name":..., {"current_weather":{...}},{"forecast_weater":{...}}}

Comment: @nimrodserok there's no problem with date but get the object in current_weather{} and forcast_weather{}

Comment: @RamaAstadipati please update the details in your question. and this is not clear JSON, can you provide valid JSON?

Comment: @turivishal sorry for faq its too long so i delete a few and i accidentally delete forecast_weatter dt

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2cJ0qkHS-Fl) solves your issue?

Comment: not yet @nimrodserok, it keep doesnt get response i want

Comment: So please provide the response you want for your input documents

Comment: @nimrodserok {"id":..., "name":..., {"current_weather":{...}},{"forecast_weater":{...}}}something like this, or may be have another way more simply to read

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_0il9RxUl6F) solves your issue?

Comment: yes man, this is what i want, i learn so much tonight, thank you @nimrodserok

Answer (score 0):

how to call object current_weather and forecast_weather is call $ this funct obj inside $project like so

```
{
$project: {
  id: 1,
  lat: 1,
  forecast_weather: "$forecast.forecast_weather",
  name: "$forecast.name"
}
}
```

and if we have another collections to join then just add another lookup and add call it in this func, it solved by [@nimrodserok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18482310/nimrod-serok) in comments